# Serial numbers on bottom bracket housing from a 50s era Schwinn?

Tags: bottom-bracket, identify-this-bike

Can someone please explain what these three numbers mean on the pedal crank housing?
I believe this to be the pedal crank housing from a 1956 Spitfire Ladies Bike.

[image: Serial reads M0D502 (small top left) The Serial reads 46772 (medium right) The large Serial reads 13 5 124]

The Schwinn Serial reads M0D502 (hard to see but top left)
The next number reads 46772 (medium right)
The large number reads 13 5 124

One of my concerns is this... The Schwinn serial numbers that date the bike to the fall of 1954 or 1956, but I believe the Serial numbers for 54 and the 56 were located on the Left Rear Dropout - not located on the bottom bracket of the pedal crank housing.
**Why would this be?**

Additionally **what does the 46772 indicate?** and **what does the 13 5 124 indicate?**

Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: Not much help but FWIW, the number on my early-1970's Schwinn Suburban is on the steering housing, two letters followed by six digits, in the range of HK549xxx. I presume that is the frame's serial number since it's both highly visible and the only number I can find.

Comment: Again, dunno about this case, but other numbers on a piece often indicate model number, mold number if cast, and manufacture date.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this is a Schwinn bicycle?

None of the numbers on the BB match the Schwinn serial number formats of the 1950s.

With all the numbers stamped on the BB it looks like Sears-Roebuck.

The 46772 might be the Sears catalog number.

Answer (score 1):

https://bikehistory.org/schwinn.php?serial=M0D502

This site attempts to decode the serial number, and if it is "M zero D five zero two" then the decoded result is

```
Congrats! Your bike is an original Chicago Schwinn.
Unfortunately the serial number you entered was used twice by Schwinn
meaning there are two possible dates for your bike...
Built: 08/13 to 08/23 of 1954 or... 
Built: 09/06 to 09/07 of 1956.
```

---

https://bikehistory.org/catalogs/1956.html

https://bikehistory.org/catalogs/1954.html

And more catalogues may be found at https://bikehistory.org/catalogs/
So you might browse through looking for something that matches your bike.

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% that is a Murray bicycle.  Mod  stands for. Murray Ohio and the letter d is the year 1939 nice bike!

Comment: Can you provide any corroborating evidence?  A link to something supporting your claim?

Comment: An indicator that it's a Schwinn would be the welded on kickstand housing located on the chain stays.